Why does Ubuntu 24.04 log me out after some time and kills all processes
Why does Ubuntu 24.04 log me out after some time and kills all processes?
I'm trying to process imagery on my desktop and this periodic log out and killing processes is making my computer almost useless.  I read all the help, and changed my settings to never lock the screen, but it still logs me out after a while.  I cannot find any logs of these events.  I've seen others with similar problems, but none of the suggestions I've tried work.

"periodic log out" has nothing to do with locking the screen.

Do you have .crash files in /var/crash with creation dates/times the correspond to the logout events?

"process imagery" suggests high memory usage. How much RAM is installed? Do you have Swap set up? If so, is it being used? Do you know how to monitor memory and swap use?

There are no crash files.  I have 64 G of memory and 71 G of swap.  56 G of memory was used and about 7 G of swap.  I believe memory use is part of the problem, but have not been able to track it down.  I did manage to complete the processing by restricting the memory use to under 50G and extending the processing time.

Unexpected logout typically occurs under two conditions: 1) Desktop crash due to a bug...but apport automatically generates a .crash file when that occurs. 2) Memory demand greater than RAM+Swap. The kernel has an Out-Of-Memory detector (called "OOM-Killer") that kills the desktop session rather than crash the whole system. It's deliberate, so not a crash. OOM-Killer events are logged in syslog and journal.

I tried the process again with adaptive memory enabled and it crashed.  When I checked the journal, I did not see any entries.  I did not check syslog.  While the memory required was more than physical memory, it was less than physical memory plus swap.  The free command showed most of the memory in the buffer.  Could it be that the process is trying to use the buffer and it's limited by physical memory?
